# php как добавлять к дате календарные месяцы?

Tags: php, дата

Собственно, есть вот такой код у меня:

```
$date_do_test = date_create($date3);
            $date_do_new = date_modify($date_do_test, $diff.'month');

            $data_all = date_format($date_do_new, 'd.m.Y');

            if ($diff==0) {
            echo "0";
            } else {
            echo date_format($date_do_new, 'd.m.Y');

            }
```

вполне хорошо от части работает, если числа месяца от 1 до 30. Но если в месяце 31 день, то к примеру, если к 31.03.18 добавить ТРИ месяца, то выводит 01.07.18 вместо 30.06.18.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно исправить?

Comment: И наоборот, т.к. отталкивающая дата, скажем, 31.03.18, чтобы спустя потом снова месяц, было 31.07.18, а не 30.07.18, т.е. последнее число месяца.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$time = strtotime("now");
$timenow = date("Y-m-d", $time); // 2018-06-04
$newdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", $time)); // 2018-07-04
$newdate1 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+2 month", $time)); // 2018-08-04
$newdate2 = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+3 month", $time)); // 2018-09-04

$diff = 3;
$date_do_test = date_create("2018-07-04");
$date_do_new = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+".$diff." month", strtotime(date_format($date_do_test, 'Y/m/d'))));
if ($diff==0) 
    echo "0";
else 
    echo $date_do_new; // 2018-10-04
```

можно вот так

```
<?php

$diff = 3;
$date_do_test = strtotime("2018/03/31");
$date_do_new = function() use ($date_do_test, $diff) {
    $temp = date("t", $date_do_test) == 31 ? 86400 : 0;
    return strtotime("+".$diff." month", $date_do_test) - $temp;
};

$date_do_format = date("Y-m-d", $date_do_new());
if ($diff==0) 
    echo "0";
else 
    echo $date_do_format; // 2018-06-30
```

А насчет твое проблемы это обсуждалось [gist-github](https://gist.github.com/garak/1000118)

`That behavior is perfectly expected when moving 1 month back/ahead from a 31-days month over 30-days month.`

То есть 1 день плюс к месяцу, для этого в функции удаляем один день если 31 день

`$temp = date("t", $date_do_test) == 31 ? 86400 : 0;`

`date("t", $date_do_test)` - количество дней в месяце

Comment: Если поставить дату 2018-03-31, то выведет 2018-07-01, а должно вывести 2018-06-30....

Comment: Извини опоздал, но принцип ты уже сам понял

Answer (score 1):

Вот так правильно вычислять любое приращение к дате.

```
$day = date('d.m.Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m") + 1, date("d") + 42, date("Y")));
```

Функция mktime() сама всё сделает.

Answer (score 0):

```
$diff=3;
function add_month($time, $num=1) { 
    $d=date('j',$time);  // день 
    $m=date('n',$time);  // месяц 
    $y=date('Y',$time);  // год 
  global $diff;
    $num = $diff;

    $m+=$num; 
    if ($m>12) { 
        $y+=floor($m/12); 
        $m=($m%12); 

        if (!$m) { 
            $m=12; 
            $y--; 
        } 
    } 


    if ($d==date('t',$time)) { 
        $d=31; 
    } 

    while(true) { 
        if (checkdate($m,$d,$y)){ 
            break; 
        } 
        $d--; 
    } 

    return mktime(0,0,0,$m,$d,$y); 
} 
echo date('d.m.Y',add_month(strtotime('2015-03-31')));
```

Использовал глобальную переменную, т.к. от нее все зависит, сколько месяцев прибавить, $diff=3; и вуаля. Вопрос закрыт.